# eslint error cannot find modle 'es-lint-plugin-jsx-a11y'

Tags: node.js, eslint

using eslint with atom I get an error "ERROR while running ESLint: Failed to load plugin jsx-a11y: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y'".

I don't want to use a11y because accessibility is not an issue in my app. When I npm install it though, an unspecific error comes:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak7Qj.png)

I tried to delete the node_modules folder and npm install all packages again.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the problem by updating the eslint packages to these versions:

```
"eslint": "^3.19.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-meteor": "^0.3.4",
"eslint-plugin-graphql": "^0.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-meteor": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
```

Comment: this have to be added in devDependencies in package.json.

Comment: This solution worked for me but I had to remove `"eslint": "^3.19.0"`, delete package-lock.json, and delete node_modules folder. And then run `npm install` again.